# How can I get data from row in table with on row button? (javascript or knockoutjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I got a table that is populated by Knockoutjs, I got one button for each row and I need to get de data on the first column from the row where the clicked button is.

Here is what I got so far:

HTML:

```
<tbody id="tbodyid" data-bind="foreach: listadepacs">
    <tr>
        <td style="display: none" data-bind="attr: {id : IdPac}"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: NombrePaciente"></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['algo'];?></td>
        <td>
            <button class="tag label label-info" onclick="vma.btnFicha();">
                <a><i class="remove glyphicon glyphiconD glyphicon-user glyphicon-white"></i></a>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

JS:

```
self.btnFicha = function(){
    var currentRow = $(this);
    var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
    alert(col1);
}
```

The alert didn't show anything, it raise up but without data.

Comment: Use Knockout's click handler instead of `onclick`; it'll pull through the relevant row's data for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the wrapping `<tr>` first, like this:

```
self.btnFicha = function(elm){

   var currentRow = $(elm).closest('tr');
   var col1 = currentRow.find("td:eq(1)").text();
   alert(col1);

}
```

Also, you need to change the `onclick="..."` to `onclick="vma.btnFicha(this);"`, because `this` refers to `vma`, in the function.

Comment: I edited my answer, both the function body as well as the `onclick` segment.

Comment: Thanks :) , this plus James Donnelly answers made the trick finally, I was stuck on this for days.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: You really shouldn't use this trick to get to your data. You should use the `click` binding which sends the `$data` along with the `event`, or, if you *really* want to do it in a weird way, use `ko.dataFor(HTMLElement)` to link the DOM to underlying data...